Changing the name of an Active journey
I have a customer journey that is linked to an automation. I want to change the name of this journey, and here are the steps I'm suggesting:
Click on New Version.
Update the name of the version with the new name.
Activate the journey.
My question is, do I need to make any additional updates to the automation that triggers the journey, such as the Journey Injection activity? Will it still point to the same journey even though I’ve changed its name in a specific version, like version X?

You don't need to make any further actions in the automation after changing the journey name, it will work as normal. However, the "journey entry activity" name in the automation will stay with the old journey name.
To avoid any confusion, I would recommend that before you activate the new version with the new journey name:

The automation should be stopped first
In the journey, click on the schedule part and update it with the automation schedule. Activate the journey.
Go back to the Automation. It should show a new "journey entry activity" with the current journey. Remove the old one and activate the automation.


Thank you so much that was helpfull
